# Replace case insensitive word with a line Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace

```
    var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function (err,data) {

  var formatted = data.replace(/problem(.*)/gm, 'hiding this word');

 fs.writeFile(someFile, formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
 });
});
```

for example if there is uppercase word like  PROBLEM find the someFile.It should replace it with "hiding this word".
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `i` flag: `/problem(.*)/gmi`

```js
let data = "Here is the pROblem";
let formatted = data.replace(/problem(.*)/gmi, 'hiding this word');
console.log(formatted)
```